# How to make a for loop to assign different variables to different strings in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

I am looking for an automation of variables assignment in swift :

```
for i in 1...3{

 var v[1] =  "\(response.value?.resultSet.the0.result.the[1]?.image.medium ?? "is nil")"
 var v[2] =  "\(response.value?.resultSet.the0.result.the[2]?.image.medium ?? "is nil")"
 var v[3] =  "\(response.value?.resultSet.the0.result.the[3]?.image.medium ?? "is nil")"
}
```

For each i, the idea is to assign a different variable with a different string, 
I am struggling to implement this in Swift...

Does someone has an idea ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could use map.

```
let v = (1...3).map { "\(response.value?.resultSet.the0.result.the[$0]?.image.medium ?? "is nil")" }
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, unfortunately this does not work in my case because the "the" before [$0] is not recognized anymore in my response.value, map is a good hint I will post my answer if I solve this problem

Comment: It indicates the following issue : Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type '(@escaping () -> String)'

Answer (score 0):

You can't name variables on the fly, you need to skip the loop and do

```
var v1 =  "\(response.value?.resultSet.the0.result.the[1]?.image.medium ?? "is nil")"
var v2 =  "\(response.value?.resultSet.the0.result.the[2]?.image.medium ?? "is nil")"
var v3 =  "\(response.value?.resultSet.the0.result.the[3]?.image.medium ?? "is nil")"
```

To use an array instead you can do something like

```
let array = response.value?.resultSet.the0.result.the.compactMap {$0.image.medium}
```

or a dictionary

```
var dictionary = [String: String]()
for (index, value) in response.value?.resultSet.the0.result.the.enumerated() {
    dictionary["v\(index)"] = value
}
```

Comment: The problem comes when there are hundred of variables to check :/

Comment: @charlslvn Then you shouldn't have individual variables but a collection instead, like a dictionary

Comment: Thank you Joakim, each technique seems relevant but it always comes to the same issue : 'Value of type 'troisViewController.Result' has no member 'the'

Comment: I hope that I can fix it by tonight

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var variables:[String:String] = [:]

for i in 1...3{
    variables["variable\(i)"] = "value\(i)"
}
```

this is the result

["variable2": "value2", "variable3": "value3", "variable1": "value1"]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

- Define a array **Variable**

```
var strVal = [String]()
```

- Append values from **response**.

```
let imgData = response.value?.resultSet.the0.result.the.count

for i in 0<..imgData.count{

    strVal[i] =  "\(response.value?.resultSet.the0.result.the[i]?.image.medium ?? "is nil")"

}
```

> With above code you don't need to store values individually.